# Redirect from server to app with android app links

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

In my application I have email verification flow with these steps

1. User submits form
2. Api sends email with confirmation link
3. User clicks on button inside email which redirects to api `server.my-domain.com` where user email gets confirmed
4. My server then redirects to `https://my-domain.com/account`, if android app is installed, app opens and if not, web link opens.

I have a problem with last step, i get redirected to app, but account screen does not open. And if I open `https://my-domain.com/account` link from other apps, account screen opens properly.

Here are my intents

```
  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="my-scheme"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="*.my-domain.com"/>
    <data android:host="my-domain.com"/>
  </intent-filter>
```

Could not find any solutions, my only idea is a redirect restriction from Android app links. In this case i'll have to change email confirmation flow

I use React Native, so I tried package uri-scheme
`npx uri-scheme open https://my-domain.com/account -a` and it works as expected

Comment: Do you use navigator package like React Navigation?

Comment: Yes, i do. I'm using basic configuration with my http and scheme specified